# microcontroller short circuit test

Tags: microcontroller, multimeter, short-circuit

Is there any way to test a microcontroller for short-circuit **without an oscilloscope** maybe using a multimeter? Mine is not overheating, but I cannot register any activity showing it is working.

I tried a continuity test and it came out positive {a short b/w Vs and GND} on both the 'test microcontroller' and another microcontroller that is functional; so, I am at a loss on how to proceed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perform a continuity test between VCC and GND (while the MCU is not powered). If available, toggle a GPO in a loop and measure with your DVM.

Comment: On a simple microcontroller with a single supply voltage, multimeter on diode test function between Vss and Vdd pins (out of circuit). One way should measure off scale, the other similar to a diode 600-ish on the display. Short circuit is unlikely, particularly if it is not overheating or bringing the supply voltage down. Many other things are more likely.

Comment: Please note that not all electrical/electronic faults are short circuits.  They may also be open circuits, or any mumber of mis-connections, or, since you have a microcontroller, a programming error (either writing the program, or tranferring it to the microcontroller.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider Port A (just another name for your port) and write a code to Toggle A.0 after 3 seconds while the rest of the pins of this port  and other ports are set at LOW. Use multimeter between A.0 and GND and If you see voltage fluctuations and not a constant zero voltage , meaning its fine. Repeat this for the rest of the remaining pins.Before performing this make sure that power pins and oscillator pins are not short circuited. If there is some availability of an internal RC oscillator, use that instead of external

It's obviously time consuming since this is what I came up at my own and probably this forum will answer you some other great methods.

Comment: This is a valid test -- but if the OP just wants to check if the microcontroller is working or not, he only needs to check the first pin.

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect a short circuit, you can connect your multimeter in current measurement mode in sequence with the microcontroller and measure the consumed current. A comparison between a healthy specimen and the non-working one will be especially helpful.